# Jquery newbie having problems with wrapping function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

I have almost no experience with jquery, but I have managed to piece together code that does exactly what I want as a straight html file. However, I want this to run in a Dot Net Nuke article, and from what I can tell, I need to wrap this code in a function to get it work.

```
    <div id="content"></div>    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

function parse(document){
  $(document).find("Game").each(function(){
    $("#content").append(
    '<p>'+$(this).attr('SchoolName')+
    ' '+$(this).attr('Score1')+
    ', '+$(this).attr('School2Name')+
    ' '+$(this).attr('Score2')+
    '</p>'
    );
  });
}   

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.website.com/xmlfilehere.xml', // name of file you want to parse
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parse,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Error:" + errorThrown);
    //error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}
  });
});
</script>
```

Evidently, I need to do this to the code to get it to work within DNN:

```
Getting this function to work is easy – wrap the code in a simple function and pass the jQuery object as a parameter.

(function($) {
    //Your jQuery code here
})(jQuery);
```

I've played around with it, but I can't get it work. Can someone show me how I would wrap my code in a simple function? I get errors like this when I do it:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'. Expected '}' to end a object literal.
(anonymous function)GetXMLWrapFunction.html:38
GetXMLWrapFunction.html:26
```

Comment: The unexpected ) is because you are missing a closing } for your error function.

Answer (score 0):

As MitoxBeyond has pointed out in the comments - You are missing a closing }.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.website.com/xmlfilehere.xml', // name of file you want to parse
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parse,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Error:" + errorThrown);
    //error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}
       } // <------ Missing ending bracket.
  });
```

Comment: OK, thanks! That indeed fixed the error. But I'm still having an issue with wrapping the function. So how would I rewrite the code to include this? Specifically, where I have success: parse now, what would I replace that with?

    (function($) {
        //Your jQuery code here
    })(jQuery);

Comment: just like you have written the error function, you can write the success function. The control would reach there when the response from the url is 200. It would be something like - sucess: function(data, status, jqXHR){}